# Is there any camera that can autoupload photos to a android device?

Tags: canon, dslr, android, automation

We are trying to build multiple Photobooths next to each other, which are equipped with a tablet that has a UI to select and upload certain photos in a folder. Right now we use canon 700d/750d (which are at this point roundabout 7-10years old) with flashair cards to take the pictures and transfer them to the tablet where they can be selected and uploaded. The problem is: the lag and the delay. Most of the time the pictures are nearly as fast on the tablet as you can shoot (we don't shoot RAW for some reason) but every once in a while it starts to lag and lack connection... like 20-30 min. or more...

That's the reason why I've put my question up here.
Most modern cameras are able to push selected photos to an android device nearby, but I couldn't find any that can do that automatically. At least not the low-end or middle class cameras we have. I've seen that the canon 5DMKIV seems to be able to auto upload pictures to an FTP server or a specific device on the network.

Comment: Would an EyeFi card be an option?  (I believe Toshiba FlashAir bought the technology)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like your question hinges on the _push_ aspect, where the camera is doing the driving. With respect to wireless transfer to mobile devices, cameras are _client_ devices, subject to the phone's pulling of data from the camera. Do you specifically require _push_ driven files/images?

Comment: @scottbb in IT language, a client tends to be the initiator/puller ....

Comment: @rackandboneman Right. "push email" was from the email server, pushing to the client. So the camera is the pusher, phone the puller in OP's use case. But modern devices are really more of a frequent pull request to just look like a "push-driven" interaction. For instance, Dropbox is really just frequent polling by the desktop client to look like push-driven. (I see what you mean from my original comment. I typo'd when I said "cameras are client devices", I meant to say **cameras** are **server** devices, subject to the phone's _(i.e., **client's**)_ pulling of data from the camera". Oops. =)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen we already use Toshiba wireless cards of the 4th gen. with a custom firmware on it... but Toshiba discontinued the developer support last year, so we're stuck with what we have. The problem with these SD cards seems to be that they can't connect properly, because cameras manufactured today all have their own wifi capabilities, some of the manufacturers seem to shield the SD slot to prevent Cards (like the Toschiba/Eyefi ones) to connect to anything by themself, so they don't interfere with the build-in Wifi

Comment: @scottbb Well, that's kind of the problem here. We need the photos to reliably get to the tablet. Tbh I don't care if it's push or pull, but I also wouldn't know how to come up with a reliable pull configuration right now...

Comment: @scottbb Now I had an idea, if we could search the camera (because it's already a server (haha also typo'd camera as a client)) it would be simpler, problem is... how do you search the camera over Wifi while it's operating? Wouldn't I always have to shut her down/switch to a mobile mode or smth. like that, which wouldn't let me take pictures simultaniously... that's why I'm going for the push approach...

Comment: @Killside Ah, missed the tiny "flashair" bit.   Would switching to GoPros be an option?

Comment: Oblique strategy: does it have to be wifi from the camera? Would it be acceptable to tether the cameras to a USB hub connected to a small computer, laptop, Rasp Pi, etc.? Then that device can just treat the cameras as USB mass storage devices and browse their filesystems watching for changes, and then either serve that data wirelessly to an Android phone, or hell, even just sync to Dropbox or some other regular cloud service. Is that strategy too out of bounds?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen nope sry, cameras must be manualy operated...

Comment: @scottbb now we're talking. ; ) I already had the idea... Problem with that was, that the camera doesn't differentiate between a pc or a android device or whatever... the protocolls are closed in such a way that if you plug something into the camera it automatically assumes that you a) have software to drive the camera or b) have software that pulls the data from it. but either way you always loose the capability to shoot while it's plugged in (at least in the non pro range... -.-) (and sry for bad wording... not a native speaker ^.^°)

Comment: @scottbb and on the other hand: a laptop would use to much space (that's why we went with a tablet in the first place) an option could be a touchscreen attached to a Rasp Pi... but then again how do you overcome the problem with the continuous shooting while it's connected? I couldn't find anything about overriding the protocolls for plugged in USB devices for example for our canon cameras...

Comment: @scottbb and to add insult to injury: even though a thethered connection would be feasable the lack of freedom of movement could potentially be a dealbreaker (at least for some (e.g. we have a lot of untrained photographers in our studios. Don't want anybody to trip and break their neck or suffocate because I insisted to use wires ^.^° bureaucracy and stuff... also that wouldn't look to nice in my CV... but i digress))

Comment: Hmm. This is the problem with design-type questions at Stack Exchange sites. A lot of the back-and-forth comments are just teasing out the details of what you're asking about. I had the impression that you wanted a single tablet to connect to all of the cameras (i.e., a "central operator" working the cameras). But it sounds like you want a tablet-per-camera setup, so that the photo booth users can operate the camera / pick the photos. Is that correct? Because you said "multiple photo booths next to each other", my suggestion of a single computer was "behind the scenes", cables taped down, etc.

Comment: @scottbb huh, interesting thought... didn't think of that option before, but I don't think that's an option. Too many photobooths (photos) to let a single or more person/s select the files that need to be uploaded (we're talking 2000 photographed objects a day with at least 3 pictures per object) So yeah, I need to build a tablet-per-camera setup. Sry for the inconvinience.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your issue, but perhaps it's a question of the Android App? I've played with **Camera Connect & Control** _RupiApps_ interfacing to my Nikon D7200 via WiFi and it or a similar App may do what you want. However I found that the D7200 will eat batteries with WiFi enabled. I'm pretty sure this App and others can be run from Phone or Tablet, although I only tried my phone.

Comment: Another Android App you may want to look at is **SLR Booth Pro** . It seems to be aimed at doing the same kind of thing, although perhaps not in the same way. The support list includes WiFi on your Canon 750D among others.